# How can I show the correct value in jtextfields when selecting a cell in a JTable with filter and search function in Java?

Tags: java, swing, search, filter, jtable

How do I obtain a value of a cell in a jtable.

I already have it working but I have encountered a problem which lead me to being stuck in it for a few mins now.

when selecting a cell i can make it show in the jtextfields with no problem, when i click justin i can make it show justin. when i click mary i can make it show mary. But the problem arose when i tried the search function of my code. When i try to search for mary then click mary, it shows justin instead of mary.

This is how it currently is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTw8Y.png)

This is how it looks like when using it normally (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZP6Y.png)

This is where the problem began (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lomAM.png)

This is what im currently using for it to show in the jtextfields

```
DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel)table1.getModel();

        String tblsport = tblModel.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(),1).toString(); 
        String tblname = tblModel.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(),2).toString(); 
        String tblmeal = tblModel.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(),3).toString(); 
        name.setText(tblname);
        sport.setText(tblsport);
        meal.setText(tblmeal);
```

and for the sorting, i use this currently

```
public void filter(String name){
        DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel)table1.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> (tblModel);
        table1.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(name));
    }
```

and this is how i called the filter

```
private void filterKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        String search = filter.getText().toUpperCase();
        filter(search);
    }
```

I already put the code above so I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: You don't show how you call `filter()`
You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My guess is that you’re not taking the sort order into account.  The TableModel is never sorted;  only the *view* (meaning, the JTable) is sorted.  This means that, for example, row 5 in the JTable may not correspond to row 5 in the TableModel.  Instead of table1.getSelectedRow(), use `table1.convertRowIndexToModel(table1.getSelectedRow())`.